# Macro execution for only odd values

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to implement a macro that takes only odd values into the algorithm. My strategy thus far is as follows:

```
%macro TEST;
    %do i=1 %TO 5;
        %IF %SYSFUNC(MOD(&i,2)=1) %THEN %DO;
        ALGORITHM 
    %END 
%END 

%MEND TEST;

%TEST
```

But I receive several errors stating that the 'Macro keyword do appears as text', among others. How might I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an evaluation on the logical value

```
%IF %SYSEVALF(%SYSFUNC(MOD(&i,2))=1,BOOLEAN) %THEN %DO;
```

You have a few syntax errors, here is a version that works:

```
%macro TEST();
    %do i=1 %TO 5;
        %IF %sysevalf(%SYSFUNC(MOD(&i,2))=1,boolean) %THEN %DO;
            %put &i - ALGORITHM ;
        %END ;
    %END ;

%MEND TEST;

%TEST();
```

Produces:

```
15014  %TEST();
1 - ALGORITHM
3 - ALGORITHM
5 - ALGORITHM
```

Answer (score 3):

Since no-one else has suggested this, how about using `%by`? E.g.

```
%macro TEST;
    %do i=1 %TO 5 %by 2;
        %put i = &i;
    %END;
%MEND TEST;

%TEST
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a lot of semi-colons.  You also have placed the `=1` test into the middle of your `%sysfunc()` macro function call.

```
%macro TEST;
%do i=1 %TO 5;
  %IF %SYSFUNC(MOD(&i,2))=1 %THEN %DO;
    %put &i is odd ;
  %END ;
%END;

%MEND TEST;

%TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 0 (and missing) evaluates to false, and anything else to true, you can simply remove the "=1".

```
%macro TEST;
    %do i=1 %to 5;
        %if %sysfunc(mod(&i,2)) %then %do;
            %put &i.;
        %end;
    %end;
%mend TEST;

%TEST;
```